# The `fields` option must be a list or tuple or "__all__". Got str

Tags: django

I am trying to create comment for my article model but i am having issue in the serializer part where it says

```
The `fields` option must be a list or tuple or "__all__". Got str.
```

I already included the parts that are needed,but i don't know where the problem is coming from.

**Models.py**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author1')
    article = models.OneToOneField(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author2')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class CommentCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('content')

    def create(self, validated_data):
     return Comment.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
fields = ('content',)
```

This is because, **`('content')`** is a string with *unnecessary brackets*, where as **`('content',)`** is a ***tuple***

---

Alternatively, you can try this too...

```
fields = ['content']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked, i wasn't able to accept the answer because of time limit coming from stackoverflow.First one is fine,thanks a lot!